# Parse.com Push notifications not being sent to all devices

Tags: android, mobile, parse-platform, cloud

I've created an app that is currently being used to notify people about the happenings in and around our college using Parse's push notifications service.
I have close to a 1000 downloads so far.

However, when I send a push it gets delivered to only about 600 devices.

Can someone help me with what's happening?

Comment: It could be, that you have 1000 Downloads but less users of your app (maybe a few personse uninstalled your application)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple possibilities that come to mind:

1. Already mentioned but a good point is that users could have installed, created a user, then uninstalled and are no longer using the app.
2. Some users could have opted to not receive push notifications and therefore would not be sent push notifications.

You can check to see how many people have opted to receive push notifications by looking at how many rows you have in the _installations table. If the number is close to the 600 then likely the rest of the users have opted out of push notifications. If the number is closer to the 1000 mark when they uninstalled your app they would no longer receive the push notifications.

You may consider this option as well to see how many users have uninstalled. [This stackoverflow article may help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603774/how-we-know-if-our-app-uninstalled-from-iphone)